# Регулярка для вынимания текста между первым и последним знаком

Tags: регулярные-выражения, shell

Например, есть текст

```
блаблабла[блабла][][[[[[[[бла][]][]]]][]]]]]блаблаблаблабла]
```

Как мне взять текст между самой первой открывающейся квадратной скобкой и самой последней закрывающейся квадратрой скобкой **с помощью регулярок в Shell**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "блаблабла[блабла][][[[[[[[бла][]][]]]][]]]]]блаблаблаблабла]" | \
  sed "s/^[^[]*\[//;s/\][^]]*$//"`